# travelpayouts hotel api signature not working

Tags: php

I have created hotel api in travelpayouts and also created signature but its give response as a error code 3 (means access denied) Please find my code bellow.

```
$hash =    md5("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:2:2017–01–01:2017–05–18:1:USD:192.168.1.1:HKT:ru:20:0");
$url = "http://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/search/start.json";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch) or exit(curl_error($ch));
$searchData = json_decode($data, true);
$search_id = $searchData['search_id'];
```

Comment: Is it possible that you also need to provide credentials when calling this API?

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are used the date in the past "2017–01–01". But this API works only with date in the future. If after that you still will have error - go here https://support.travelpayouts.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and send request to the support.